# Bootstrap 4 beta 2. How to make equal width li inside different col which are stretched to screen width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've spent much time, but can't get it work.
As you can see on fiddle, I have three main blocks (light gray), and multiple number of blocks inside. I need those little dark blocks to be equal width relatively to the width of the screen or to .thisBlock block (the same).
All divs are on their places. The markup is rather difficult, so I've leaved the most important blocks. 
https://jsfiddle.net/nv5aznym/4/

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-12">


    <div class="row no-gutters">

      <div class="col c">

        <div class="block">
           <ul class="ul d-flex justify-content-between">
            <li class="d-inline-block">1</li>
            <li class="d-inline-block">2</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col c">

        <div class="block">
           <ul class="ul d-flex justify-content-between">
            <li class="d-inline-block">11</li>
            <li class="d-inline-block">22</li>
            <li class="d-inline-block">33</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col c">

        <div class="block">
           <ul class="ul d-flex justify-content-between">
            <li class="d-inline-block">11</li>
            <li class="d-inline-block">22</li>
            <li class="d-inline-block">33</li>
            <li class="d-inline-block">44</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


  </div>
```

And CSS:

```
.c {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0 2px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}
.ul {
      padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #dfe0e2;
    padding: 5px;
}
.ul li {
  background-color: #5d5d5d;
    color: #919191;
    cursor: default;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 2px;
}
```

Comment: You can't do this with CSS. There is no mechanism to equalise dimensions between elements that do not share a parent. You need javacript.

Comment: I was hope flex can handle it... Bad news... Can you write it as answer, not comment, I'll accept it if nobody will suggest anything helpful.

Comment: So the fiddle doesn't look the way you want it to? Can you draw a mockup of what it should look like?

Answer (score 1):

use this jQuery code:

```
var totalLi = $('.thisBlock li').length;

$('.thisBlock .c').each(function(index, element){
    var cLi = $(element).find('li').length;
    $(element).css({'flex-basis':cLi/totalLi *100 +'%'})
})
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/acLx1mod/](https://jsfiddle.net/acLx1mod)