# Jquery. How to get new parameters of elements after window resize using each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, live

**Hello.**

```
var repo = {
    doSmth: function(){
       $('.block').each(function(i, obj) {
           console.log($(this).width());
       })       
    }
}

(function() {

    repo.doSmth();
    function onResize(){
        repo.doSmth();

    };
    $(window).on('resize',onResize);

})();
```

When I open the page, I see the real sizes of elements in the console, but when I change window size doSmth() is working, but it shows initial elements' size.
I need actual data after each refresh. How can I do this? I need a kind of live functionality on resize.

Comment: You need to calculate the percentage of the size change? I mean, if the size was 100px, and inside block was 50px - when the client resizes his page to 110px, the inside block should be resized to 55px?

Comment: There is one parent block. It is contains variable number of li elements. CSS justify (bootstrap 4, flex) li to full width of parent block (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/ -> d-flex justify-content-between), so that I have full outer width of parent container. Then I get usefull horisontal li space and make them equal width and full width relatively to parent element. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47976807/bootstrap-4-beta-2-how-to-make-equal-width-li-inside-different-col-which-are-st - here is what I need to do.

Comment: @JohnSmith can you share the HTML for this. fiddle would help.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get your code to run, so I wrote something else that should do what you need:

```
$(window).on('resize',onResize);

 function onResize() {
 var block = $('.block');
 block.each(function (){
   console.log($(this).width());
 });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

console.log($(this).width());

I thought the problem could be that the 'this' object had changed.

Comment: could you elaborate on how `this` object has changed?